# New Flyway migrations break existing jOOQ generated code

Tags: java, flyway, jooq

I currently use jOOQ to generate Java code from my database and Flyway to manage my binary (Java) migrations as well as SQL migrations.

However, I run into problems when I modify existing tables. For example, if I were to drop a column in one migration and a past binary migration was dependent on that column, the migration will have a syntax error because the field wouldn't exist in jOOQ anymore.

I know I could just comment out the body of the migration but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of Flyway or any sort of database version manager if I can't rerun my migrations or makes it very tedious (run 1 migration, uncomment, run next, generate jOOQ, etc)

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Are you saying you are using [Flyway Java migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java) and in those migrations you are using jOOQ to assist with the migration?

Comment: Yes exactly, the problem is that the generated jooq code depends on the state of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue this is a workflow problem.

You are effectively upgrading an API with each migration, expecting legacy consumers of that API to continue to work would be nothing short of miraculous.

jOOQ is a great tool but using it in this context (to assist migrations) is certainly going to lead to trouble.

My suggestion would be to rethink you schema evolution strategy; using raw SQL, which comes naturally to Flyway, and leave jOOQ for exclusively assisting your application instead.